# Can I tap iPhone simulator back button with the help of script in UIAutomation Instruments? If yes, then how to do the same?

Tags: javascript, ios-ui-automation

I want to close the application, kill it (its instance) from background and re-launch it again.
So is there any way to do this, directly or indirectly??

Answer (score 1):

Start instruments from the command line, and write a system-level script to run it twice with two different scripts. When the first run finished, your app will be stopped, and relaunched, when you start the second run. Your system-level script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
instruments -t Template.tracetemplate -e UIASCRIPT script1.js
instruments -t Template.tracetemplate -e UIASCRIPT script2.js
```